# Is there a reason to make every WCF call Async?

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

Is there a reason to make every WCF service call Async?

I was having this discussion with my partner. He would like to make every WPF service call Async to avoid locking the UI (it is a desktop WPF application). I am against this idea. I do not feel an Async call is needed in most cases, and when it is needed both the RequestingClass and the DataManager should be coded specifically to handle the Async call.

My arguments for this is that is far more code to setup callbacks for everything and it is very confusing. I also think this could cause a performance decrease, although I haven't verified this yet. His argument is that sometimes you are getting a lot of data back and it would lock up the UI, and it isn't that much work to setup the WCF calls like this (he also doesn't find the following code confusing).

We've both never worked with the WCF server before, so I thought I'd give him the benefit of doubt and ask here for some other opinions.

For example:

**My Way:**

```
public override User GetById(int id)
{
    return new User(service.GetUserById(id));
}
```

It locks the UI, UserDataManager, and WCF service channel until the WCF server returns with the User DataTransferObject, however it is easy to understand and quick to code. It would be used for most WCF service calls unless it actually expected a delay in getting data, in which case the DataManager would be setup to handle Async calls.

**His Way:**

```
public override void GetById(int id, Action<UserGroup> callback = null)
{
    // This is a queue of all callbacks waiting for a GetById request
    if (AddToSelectbyIdQueue(id, callback))
        return;

    // Setup Async Call
    var wrapper = new AsyncPatternWrapper<UserDTO>(
        (cb, asyncState) => server.BeginGetUserById(id, cb, asyncState),
        Global.Instance.Server.EndGetUserById);

    // Hookup Callback
    wrapper.ObserveOnDispatcher().Subscribe(GetByIdCompleted);

    // Run Async Call
    wrapper.Invoke();
}

private void GetByIdCompleted(UserDTO dto)
{
    User user = new User(dto);

    // This goes through the queue of callbacks waiting 
    // for this method to complete and executes them
    RunSelectIdCallbacks(user.UserId, user);
}
```

Callback queue on base class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Adds an item to the select queue, or a current fetch if there is one
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">unique object identifier</param>
/// <param name="callback">callback to run</param>
/// <returns>False if it needs to be fetched, True if it is already being
/// fetched</returns>
protected virtual bool AddToSelectbyIdQueue(int id, Action<T> callback)
{
    // If the id already exists we have a fetch function already going
    if (_selectIdCallbacks.ContainsKey(id))
    {
        if(callback != null)
            _selectIdCallbacks[id].Add(callback);
        return true;
    }

    if (callback != null)
    {
        List<Action<T>> callbacks = new List<Action<T>> {callback};
        _selectIdCallbacks.Add(id, callbacks);
    }

    return false;
}

/// <summary>
/// Executes callbacks meant for that object Id and removes them from the queue
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">unique identifier</param>
/// <param name="data">Data for the callbacks</param>
protected virtual void RunSelectIdCallbacks(int id, T data)
{
    if (_selectIdCallbacks.ContainsKey(id))
    {
        foreach (Action<T> callback in _selectIdCallbacks[id])
            callback(data);

        _selectIdCallbacks.Remove(id);
    }
}
```

It does not lock the UI, the DataManager, or the WCF Service Channel, however a lot of extra coding goes into it.

The AsyncPatternWrapper is in our application regardless. It is something that allows us to make Async WCF calls and subscribe a callback event

**EDIT**
We do have a wrapper which we can use from the UI thread to wrap any DataManager call. It executes the Synchronous method on a BackgroundWorker, and executes a callback against the results.

The majority of the extra code is to prevent locking the DataManager and the WCF Service channel.

Comment: Consider evaluating the CTP release of the new C# "async/await" feature. It is designed to make writing this sort of code much easier. We would be happy to get your feedback at the async forum. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/async.aspx

Comment: @Eric: Thanks, I'm looking into it now and so far I'm liking it!

Comment: @Eric: Can you point me towards any good tutorials/walkthroughs about using this with a WCF service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your partner is correct; you shouldn't block the UI thread.

As an alternative to async calls, you can also make synchronous calls in a background thread using a BackgroundWorker or the ThreadPool.

Comment: We actually do have a wrapper that does that... it executes the DataManager call in a BackgroundWorker thread to stop locking the UI, however that is called from the UI thread not the DataManager (Reason is that WPF can't alter objects created on the UI thread from a BackgroundWorker). I am concerned about all the extra coding to just stop locking the DataManager and the WCF Channel. I'll update my question.

Comment: Would you still recommend the 2nd way? I have no problem going with it if it is the better way of doing things, but don't want to over-complicate things if they are not needed

Comment: @Rachel: You should still use a separate thread for web service calls, just use Dispatcher.Invoke() to update the UI when the call returns - plenty of info via Google.

Answer (score 2):

A few things worth noting:

1. Any WCF call can potentially block until its timeout period and you should take this into account.  It makes for a poor user experience when the UI is blocked in the case of a lost connection.  Calls can also run slower than usual, if, for instance, the server is bogged down.
2. Even if you're not wrapping the calls for asynchronous purposes, you will probably already want some wrapping of calls to the proxy.  This is because any call on the proxy can potentially put the channel in a faulted state and, if this occurs, you **have** to call Abort() on the channel or you can leak resources.  See [this post](http://vanryswyckjan.blogspot.com/2007/05/exploring-wcf-close-vs-abort-confusion.html) and [this other post](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/erwyn/archive/2006/12/09/WCF-Service-Proxy-Helper.aspx) for some additional information.  WCF proxies can't be used like normal classes and necessarily involve additional wrapping if you want to use them in a production scenario.  This is largely unavoidable, as it's a consequence of the additional boundary cases and unpredictable behaviors introduced by the remote communication requirements.

Comment: I removed a lot of the code so I could show only relevant code. All service calls in the DataManagers are wrapped in something which catches exceptions/faults and ensures the channel stays open. Most DataManager calls are wrapped in something which executes them on a BackgroundWorker and stops UI blocking. Good advice though :)